# Code for unziping file

Tags: 8

I am creating a module for Drupal 8, in which I want to upload and extract zip file to a root directory. Inside `moduleSettingsForm.php` file, I have a `function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)`. I am getting all the values of uploaded file but I am unable to extract the content of file.

So is there any way to do this in Drupal 8?

Comment: Checking the Drupal 8 core docs, I've found a Zip class which might work for this purpose. Please see the documentation [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Archiver%21Zip.php/class/Zip/8).

Answer (score 4):

There are a Drupal 8 Way how to unzip a ZIP archive:

```
use Drupal\Core\Archiver\Zip;
use Drupal\Core\Archiver\ArchiverException;

try {
  $zip = new Zip('/path/to/archive/file.zip');
  $zip->extract('/path/to/archive');
  // Remove the source zip file if necessary.
  // $zip->remove($file);
  // Shows list (array) of those unzipped files regarding the zip file folder.
  var_dump($zip->listContents());
}
catch (ArchiverException $exception) {
  watchdog_exception('custom_module_name', $exception);
  // Some code if the error of unzip will happen.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you have the file uri of the uploaded file, this stops being a Drupal problem and starts being a PHP problem.

You should take a look at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889025/unzip-a-file-with-php) for a full description.

What you are looking for is this snippet.

> ```
> $zip = new ZipArchive;
> $res = $zip->open('file.zip'); 
> if ($res === TRUE) {
>   $zip->extractTo('/myzips/extract_path/');
>   $zip->close();
> }
> ```

Comment: "$zip = new \ZipArchive" worked Thanks a lot!!